# Populating the price of a product into a dropdown from a parent dropdown list

Tags: php, dropdown

**--I am using the query below to select all product ID's**

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.Product_Name FROM products p, store_inventory s WHERE p.ProductID = s.Product_ID";             
    $statement2 = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement2->execute();
    $products2 = $statement2;
```

**--Using a Select to Choose the products**

```
<label id="label">Product ID by Name:</label><br>
          <select id="ProductID" name="ProductID" style="width: 300px">
          <option>Select Product:</option
          <?php foreach($products2 as $p) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $p['ProductID']; ?>"><?php echo$p['Product_Name']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
```

How would I get the product ID and display the price(s) into a dropdown list?
Id like to select Item_Price from products where ProductID = :ProductID but not sure how to complete this on the same page.

Comment: Ajax..look it up. You'd use Jquery to run ajax onchange of the product ID drop down, then ajax through jquery will build and display another select with prices. You'll need jquery, another php file to contain the query and echo out the html for it

Comment: you can you use `AJAX`